# how to update the download icon if a file is download already in page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the list of book materials in my server.when i click the file,it will download automatically.but i need to change the download icon like the icon should specify the file is already downloaded .how to update the using jquery .

Comment: what should happen if the visitor aborts the download?

Comment: it will be showing cancel Button if the user aborts the download

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this without javascript. Just make use of the visited link pseudoselector. Once user clicks to download, it is a 'visited' link and the display should change.

jsfiddle doesn't allow link navigation, but this should give you an idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/pBCap/

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x50/ff0000/000000&text=Download');
}

a:visited { 
    background: url('http://placehold.it/300x50/ff00ff/000000&text=Download');
}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the  tag inside a div tag  and change the div tag's innerHTML accordingly.

1. Initial state -

   ```
    onpageLoad(){

        <div id="iconDiv"><img src="readToDownload.png"</div>

    }
   ```
2. When user clicks download , the onClick event changed the innerHTML of the div

   ```
    onClick(){

       div.innerHTML = "<img src='downloading.png'/> ";

    }
   ```